# Renaming and Zipping Files Python - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, zip, file-rename

Just getting back into Python and am trying to build a script that will match file names, rename, zip them, and then ultimately build a control file off them (this I haven't written yet). It works on the files placed in the directory, but at the end I get the error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'A20190331.txt' -> 'B20190530.txt'. Is it rerunning my txt_files for loop in the beginning after renaming? Code is probably not optimal at this point.

```
import os
import zipfile

try:
    import zlib
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED




path = 'mypath'

txt_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        txt_files.append(file)


def create_zip(data_dt):
    for files in txt_files:
        if '.py' in files:
            continue
        elif 'A' in files:
            file_name = 'A' + data_dt + '.txt'
            name_full_path = path +'\\'+ file_name
            os.rename(files, file_name)
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile('A' + data_dt+ '.zip', mode='w')
            zf.write(name_full_path, file_name, compress_type=compression)
            zf.close()
        elif 'B' or 'C' in files:
            file_name = 'B' + data_dt + '.txt'
            name_full_path = path +'\\'+ file_name
            os.rename(files, file_name)
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile('B' + data_dt +'.zip', mode='w')
            zf.write(name_full_path, file_name, compress_type=compression)
            zf.close()
        else:
            break

create_zip('20190530')
```

Answer (score 1):

Christopher.

I see your problem immediately:

```
txt_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
for file in files:
    txt_files.append(file)
```

I believe you want to keep the path:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        txt_files.append(os.path.join(os.path.get_cwd(), file))
```

Let os.path handle the path for you -- it is portable across platforms and less error prone.

hth

Answer (score 0):

i did some modification, can you try this please , but using your way, the code will overwrite the files. 
so try this script, and tell me if you want to overwrite or  just rename and zip

```
def create_zipe(data_dt):
    for files in txt_files:
        if '.py' in files:
            continue
        elif 'ASS' in files:
            file_name = 'A' + data_dt + '.txt'
            name_full_path = path +'/'+ file_name
            os.rename(files, file_name)
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile('A' + data_dt+ '.zip', mode='w')
            zf.write(name_full_path, file_name, compress_type=compression)
            zf.close()
        elif 'C' in files or 'B' in files:
            file_name = 'B' + data_dt + '.txt'
            print(file_name)
            name_full_path = path +'/'+ file_name
            print(name_full_path)
            os.rename(files, file_name)
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile('B' + data_dt+ '.zip', mode='w')
            zf.write(name_full_path, file_name, compress_type=compression)
            zf.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the mods, was looking to overwrite and then zip.